# How to prevent deletion of entity if another entities has foreign key reference to it?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a user entity which is connected to other entities with foreign keys.

For now, if I try to delete a user entity which has references, I get this SQL error:

> DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

My goal is to check if user has references before the EF delete action and if it has - return a custom exception with text "Please delete all user references", but I still need to return a SQL exception if there any other SQL errors.

I can use `try catch` on delete action and check the `exception.message` if it has text 'DELETE statement conflicted'. But I don't like this approach and I'm wondering about better solution.

So, is there any better way to achieve this behavior?

Or if it is impossible to check it before delete action, can I understand that exception is exactly 'Reference constraint', not any other?

Comment: To avoid the built in message, you would run a a SELECT statement to seek the data BEFORE you try to delete it.  And you could do something as simple as IF RS.EOF THEN (attempt the delete only then) END IF.  As in, if the recordset fails (nothing found) do this, ELSE record WAS found so do this sort of logic ..

Comment: @easleyfixed, sorry, I wrote that user has reference with one entity, but it has a lot references with different entities. So I don't using for all of them will be good solution